# present modal view on rotate

Tags: iphone, rotation, presentmodalviewcontroller

So I have a UITableViewControler displaying a tableview in portrait mode.

As soon as i rotate the iPhone i want to present a modal view in landscape mode.

In the tableView i use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

And to handle the present the modal view:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
        if((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
        {
            NSLog(@"Push page view");
            PagingViewController *s = [[PagingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PagingView" bundle:nil];
            s.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

            [self presentModalViewController:s animated:YES];
            [s release];
        }
}
```

The modal view i have the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

And to dismiss the modal view it self, I do:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        NSLog(@"Dismiss my self");
        [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Some how this works two times.
The third time i rotate the iPhone from Portrait mode to Landscape mode, i get a bad access error.

I cant figure out what gives me the error.
Anyone care for a shot?

Comment: What line does the bad access error occur? (You can see this in the debugger.)

Comment: Whenever i try to do something in the UITableViewController after the second modal dismiss. So I suppose the UITableViewController somehow get dismissed too.

Comment: I had all kinds of issues doing something similar, way back with 3.0. Seemed like a known bug, plus race-condition. In the end, used device notifications to monitor changes; see this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500060/view-controller-not-getting-shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-messages-on

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is to implement -shouldAutorotate... and dismiss the modal view and return NO to abort rotation. Perhaps that will be sufficient to avoid any concurrency issues. If this suggestion isn't to your liking take a look at NSNotificationCenter.